# NameNode does not get started with start-all.sh

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am trying to run Hadoop on my machine as a single node cluster. I did the installation steps, so Hadoop is on my system already.

However, when I run `start-all.sh` and afterwards I check with `jps` if `NameNode` is running, this is what I get:

```
20053 Jps
19944 NodeManager
```

I already tried with running first `start-dfs.sh` and then `start-yarn.sh`, but that didn't work.

I also tried formating the `NameNode` with

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

but I cannot do that, I get the errors:

```
15/07/15 16:34:19 WARN namenode.NameNode: Encountered exception during format: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot remove current directory: /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
15/07/15 16:34:19 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: Cannot remove current directory: /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
15/07/15 16:34:19 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
15/07/15 16:34:19 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at user/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

I also tried with:

```
sudo hadoop namenode -format
```

but that didn't work either, I still get some errors.

Could someone please help me with this? I am struggling with this problem for days now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a permissions problem.

The user that you use to run the name node format needs to be the same as the user that runs the namenode process. You *can* get around this by playing with Unix filesystem permissions, but you *should not*.

For your case, you can run the start scripts as root, which is not a great idea, but probably acceptable if we're just talking about a local cluster.

Better practice would be to remove `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current` and rerun the format as the correct user. Typically, that would be something like:

```
sudo su hdfs -c "hadoop namenode -format"
```